# nosetest error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required

Tags: python, function, dictionary, nose

I am very much a noob and this is w/r/t python 2.7 and an exercise I'm working through on *Learn Python the Hard Way* ([link to ex47](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex47.html)) - The file below is named ex47_tests.py and the error I get is related to running `nosetests` to the directory I'm working in.

According to `nosetests`, the error is from the `test_map()` function at the line `west.add_paths({'east', start})` and it states: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence at element #0 has length 4; 2 is required` but I cannot understand what the problem is... here's the test file:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex47.game import Room


def test_room():
    gold = Room("GoldRoom", 
                """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                door to the north.""")
    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assert_equal(gold.paths, {})

def test_room_paths():
    center = Room("Center", "Test room in the center.")
    north = Room("North", "Test room in the north.")
    south = Room("South", "Test room in the south.")

    center.add_paths({'north': north, 'south':south})
    assert_equal(center.go('north'), north)
    assert_equal(center.go('south'), south)

def test_map():
    start = Room("Start", "You can go west and down a hole.")
    west = Room("Trees", "There are trees here, you can go east.")
    down = Room("Dungeon", "It's dark down here, you can go up.")

    start.add_paths({'west': west, 'down': down})
    west.add_paths({'east', start})
    down.add_paths({'up': start})

    assert_equal(start.go('west'), west)
    assert_equal(start.go('west').go('east'), start)
    assert_equal(start.go('down').go('up'), start)
```

For reference, the game.py file contains the `Room` class that has the `add_paths` function (method?):

```
class Room(object):

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.paths = {}

    def go(self, direction):
        return self.paths.get(direction, None)

    def add_paths(self, paths):
        self.paths.update(paths)
```

I've reviewed this several times and I have successfully run the code for `west.add_paths({'east', start})` within the game.py file but when I run the `nosetests`I keep getting the same error.  At the point in the code where the error occurs, my interpretation is that `west` contains an empty `{}` which should `update` without issue, no? Can someone provide some insight as to why this isn't working and where the error comes from?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug in the code is coming from this call:

```
west.add_paths({'east', start})
```

The correction to be made with this, is that you want to update with a dictionary, not a set:

```
west.add_paths({'east': start})
```

This error is reproducible with the following example when you try to update a dictionary with a set:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update({'east','start'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required
```

To provide more clarity on the bug, if you go to your interpreter and check the type of this:

Notice the comma between 'east' and 'start'

```
>>> print(type({'east', 'start'}))
<type 'set'>
```

Notice the colon between 'east' and 'start'

```
>>> print(type({'east': 'start'}))
<type 'dict'>
```

Comment: Hi idjaw, nosetests told me the line the error originated from so it was easy to find and I understand the error you re-produced but I guess I am confused as to why when I tested `west.add_paths({'east': start})` within game.py I didn't receive the error. I reviewed `west.path` before 'update' and `west.path` after the `update` and I successfully saw that the room object made it into the the empty {}.

Comment: Hey @jmb277! :) Take a careful look again at what you wrote. You wrote this: `{'east': start}`. Look at the first line I wrote in my solution indicating the bug, it is written as: `{'east', start}`. Notice the comma between east and start. *that* is the bug.

Comment: Hi idjaw, I seriously looked at those two code snippets you put down and I wondered allowed if I was being trolled b/c I completely missed the `:` vs `,` difference - it's working now and I really appreciate your patience - thank you.

Comment: @jmb277 Cheers dude. It's not an easy one to catch. :) Good luck with your learning. Keep it up.